# Замена части url

Tags: nginx, url

У меня есть сайт с подобными url - [www.domain.com/ru_ru/articles/xxxxxxx/](http://www.domain.com/ru_ru/articles/xxxxxxx/)

Существует ли возможность в nginx заменить "ru_ru" на иное значение, например "ru"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте в локейшене что-то типа:

```
rewrite "^/(ru)_\1(/.*)$" $1$2 permanent;
```

А вообще ничего не понятно. Уточните хотя бы цели, какой движок сайта, как формируются ссылки. Может, родится какой-то хороший выход из ситуации.

Comment: Сайт статичный на HUGO, делаю многоязычный сайт, а это можно сделать только используя коды языков в url, а мне надо вместо кода языка использовать сокращенное название страны (например вместо "en-gb" использовать "uk") В самом Хуго так сделать не получится.

Comment: попробуйте моё решение для ru_ru внутри location /